# When controlling an enemy with magic, can you cast through that enemy?

Tags: spells, shadowrun-sr5

When controlling an enemy with the *Control Actions* (German: Handlungen Beherrschen) spell, you can control the enemy as if he is a puppet, but you use *your* ability scores when doing something with the puppet.

My question now is, can I force the enemy to cast a spell when I control him with the spell? Would I have to use spells known to me or those known to the target, assuming it is able to cast spells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With *control actions*:

> You control the physical actions of your target (Core 292)

But

> You only have to concentrate to cast a spell, but your tradition
>   probably has plenty of chanting, gestures, dancing, and other things
>   to go along with it. (Core 281)
>
> Sure, you don’t necessarily need things like chants, elegant hand
>   gestures, muttered curses, and a holistic philosophy to sling spells
>   and summon spirits, but it sure helps you connect to the magic (Core
>   279)

Thus working magic is primarily an action of the mind and thus cannot be forced using this spell.

(You might be able to lead a victim of *control thoughts* to cast a spell with clever suggestions, though.)